# How to change MKCircle radius by map zoom level changed in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, mkmapview

I have an map view app, and work with `MKCircle`.

The default circle was set the radius, means while change the map view the circle will change to big or small.

I don't want this. I want to keep the size, so I think I need to change the radius while zoom level changed.

Should I need to do this in

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What will the MKCircle be used for?  It would be easier to use an annotation with image of circle instead of an overlay.  Annotations stay a constant size.

Comment: I want use circle group the nearest annotations, and show the count of the annotations.